# How to Avoid Network Internet Egress from Singapore to Americas from Cloud SQL on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm looking to my billing and I realized that there is

Network Internet Egress from Singapore to Americas charge on my billing which is large number.

I would like to know how to set cloud SQL to avoid this charge.

Currently I fixed Authorized networks just only for my server (locate same region) but look like the  Network Internet Egress from Singapore to Americas is still continue.

Please suggest me what should I do next.

Regards

Comment: Your question does not provide details. Why is Cloud SQL in Singapore? Why is network traffic from the Americas? What is generating that traffic?

Comment: My service is base on Bangkok and I choose Singapore as location instance. So far, I don't know why lot of traffic from America. Any solution to check?

Comment: Your question does not provide details.